# Missing arguments in SQL 2012 command line installation

Tags: sql-server, sql, command-line-arguments, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

I am new to SQL installation through command line.

- We are developing an application and using Installation Shield.
- I need to install SQL server on clients pc, so I am using command line silent installation of SQL.
- Problem is only MS-SQL 2012 server setup(English) is getting installed. I need to install complete SQL server, Native client, .NET Framework, VSS Writer, setup support files, server Browser and everything
- I am using this command to install SQL:

  ```
  SQLEXPR_x64_ENU /QS /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=1 /Action=install /INSTANCENAME=XYZ /INSTALLSQLDATADIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\  /FEATURES=SQLENGINE,REPLICATION,SNAC_SDK /SAPWD=n:4Y2cX=W3/i /SECURITYMODE=SQL /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=0
  ```

I also tried `/FEATURES=SQLENGINE, TOOLS` but it was not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a few issues with your command line, some of the switches aren't variables, some of them you need to escape with quotation marks.

To install the features you listed, you need the following features switch:

```
SQLEXPR_x64_ENU /QS /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /Action=install /INSTANCENAME=XYZ /FEATURES=SQLEngine,REPLICATION,SNAC_SDK /SAPWD="n:4Y2cX=W3/I" /SECURITYMODE=SQL /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=0
```

Ensure that the feature list does *not* have a space and any reserved characters are escaped in quotes. The MSDN documentation is unclear, it gives an example with a space as you've tried to use, but the page actually states:

> /PARAMETER="value1" "value2" "value3" for all multiple-value parameters. Using double quotation marks is recommended, but required if the value contains a space
>
> /FEATURES, which is a multivalued parameter, but its format is
> /FEATURES=AS,RS,IS without a space, comma-delimited

Ensure you have the casing correct also. See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(v=sql.110).aspx#Feature) for detailed guides on using the command line switches for a SQL installation.